# I've 'always' wondered about its etymology

Tags: meaning, etymology

What has *way* been doing in ***always*** all this time?

*etymonline*:

> **[always](https://www.etymonline.com/word/always)** (adv.)
>   mid-14c., contraction of Old English phrase *ealne weg* "all the time; quite, perpetually," literally "all the way," with accusative of space or distance, though the oldest recorded usages refer to time; … Meaning "every time" is from early 13c.

If literally the reference is to "space or distance," how did "the oldest recorded usages refer to time"? (Note the "oldest": it's not even like it has evolved/ changed later, it's **always** been so.)

To conjecture that it was on the lines of "all the way" (from one end to the other of; in or to every part of) would still leave you in the space-distance realm.

Some sources include the meaning "all the while." However, the etymological root *weg* is distinct from that of *while*, which is OE *hwīl* instead.

Comment: I think  the meaning  that  “all the way” suggests can be easily extended to a long time function. And as they suggest, this extension was present from Old English.

Comment: Given the advent of Minkowski space-time in the 20th century, perhaps not so strange.

Comment: [The PIE root is *_wegh-_, which is a motion word](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/roots.aspx?type=Indo-European&root=wegh-). When motion is involved, space and time are interrelated. _She lives three days away_ is the sort of thing anyone might say, in any language, if the means of travel is presupposed, as it almost always is. Since English has so few words that refer exclusively to time (_during, endure, duration, when, then, now_), almost all our time references are metaphoric, and spatial metaphors are quite common.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks, Prof., also for the reference. That's more of an answer.

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 Rather, as one would suspect, it's historical, way back to PIE. See JohnLawler above.

Comment: I suggest that by definition, that's about Old English and never about English…

Comment: Huh, @RobbieGoodwin ? *What* is about OE?

Comment: It's well-established in linguistics that spatial metaphors are commonly used with temporal reference, although each language has its own unique strategies for doing so. See e.g. Lakoff 1993, "The contemporary theory of metaphor".

Comment: @kris I wasn't trying to suggest that it started with Einstein's 1905 paper in Annalen der Physik.  Rather it struck me as ironic that a distance metaphor for time would become literally true in spacetime.

Comment: There is the earlier word _alway_ and it has the literal sense in its origin. _OED_ offers some explanation and  cites foreign-language parallels. _OED_ also adds: "Old English _ealne weg_ is also attested in adverbial use in its literal sense ‘all the way, the whole way’"

Answer (score 7):

I think this question deserves some attention.

No answer coming will probably be very satisfying. What is involved is [idiomatic](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/idiom) English of a very old sort.  The question references *ealne weg*  which seems the oldest available form of this idiom.

The main issue with this idiom is [*weg*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/way). The Latin cognate, [*via*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/via#etymonline_v_7751), had similar meanings with the Anglo-Saxon dialects as indicating a route, road or means. But it is clear that in at least some Anglo-Saxon dialects *weg* had taken on usage distinct from simple known definitions.

Those A-S dialects had a term for "*always*", [*simble*](https://books.google.com/books?id=oXlii1KgDngC&pg=PA875&lpg=PA875&dq=Simbel%20in%20anglo-saxon&source=bl&ots=4pY9GTXK3v&sig=kfSbWcsTxzfQEedHHmjjLIka55U&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiah5mj_O_eAhWN11MKHWwvBO0Q6AEwEnoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=Simbel%20in%20anglo-saxon&f=false) and other similar words. Obviously this is a cognate with the Latin [*semper*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/semper-). Latin and the Romance Languages retained *semper*, but *simble* seems lost in current English.

Why "all ways" survives today and *simble* has been lost is a question I cannot answer. But this is no isolated language incident. We have [*almost*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/almost#etymonline_v_10905) and [*already*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/already#etymonline_v_10918) among others with similar construction. These "single word idioms" were codified when Anglo-Norse and Anglo-Norman were merging to form the language we know today. One can guess that intercommunication played a part in why *always* survives. But I cannot point to a mechanism that caused that.

I think it fair to say that *always* is good, honest English, and old in the language. What is unsatisfying is that a search for the origin of *always* does not meet a dead end, but a dead beginning. There is really no telling what the origin of the expression is, nor how old it is. One could guess that some grammatical function in some Northwest Germanic dialects allowed  a form of "all ways" to mean the same as "always" in current English, but, now, that could only be a guess.

Answer (score 3):

Just an idea: in many southern German dialects, the word "oiwei"/"alleweil" still exists. Sounds very similar to and has the same meaning as "always", and it has been in wider use for centuries. It literally translates to "all whiles", which would put it in the temporal context the English word lacks.

Comment: A great help in furthering the etymological search. Could be even more so if we could find some reliable source(s) supporting and furthering this plausible argument.